# Trying to rewrite url for Grafana with Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

In my kubernetes cluster I would like to do monitoring so I installed grafana.

I would like to access the grafana dashboard as `http://example.com/monitoring`, so I tried to include this in my ingress configuration

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
  http:
    paths:
    - path: /monitoring/(.*)
    backend:
     serviceName: grafana
     servicePort: 80
```

The idea is to add other paths there as well, for example `/` for the website.

I noticed that Grafana redirects `http://example.com/monitoring` to `http://example.com/login`. Of course this should have been `http://example.com/monitoring/login`. What would be the preferred way to fix this. Can it be done with `ingress` or should I somehow tell Grafana that it is behind a `/monitoring` path (if possible)?

I've installed grafana using [this](http://www.allaboutwindowssl.com/2019/03/setup-prometheus-grafana-monitoring-on-azure-kubernetes-cluster-aks/) using Helm.

UPDATE: I've modified as suggested below the grafana chart's file values.yaml as follows

```
grafana.ini:
  server:
    domain: example.com
    root_url: http://example.com/monitoring/
```

Now I get:

[image]

And the heml command I use to install grafana:

```
$> helm install stable/grafana -f values.yaml --set persistence.enabled=true --set persistence.accessModes={ReadWriteOnce} --set persistence.size=8Gi -n grafana
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common problem with services that are behind an HTTP reverse-proxy. Luckily, Grafana offers a way to let it know the context path it is running behind.

In `grafana.ini` (which is most possibly supplied via a ConfigMap to its Kubernetes deployment), you need to specify the variables like the following:

```
[server]
domain = example.com
root_url = http://example.com/monitoring/
```

See the full documentation here: https://grafana.com/docs/installation/behind_proxy/

Comment: You're right, but I've installed Grafana with Helm (checkout my updated question). I've updated the values.yaml, but no luck

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri Just a guess: can you try to remove the rewrite in the ingress, only keep the path as `/monitoring/` and try again? It might be that the `root_url` instruction in Grafana causes it itself to be served from `/monitoring` context path.

Comment: It turned out to be an Ingress rewrite issue. So it works like a charm now. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Ran into same error as in this question, though I have following entries in kube-prometheus-stack/charts/grafana/values.yaml. Any clue what else to check?

grafana.ini:
...
server:
domain: sandboxgr.myorg.com
root_url: https://sandboxgr.myorg.com/

Comment: this solution worked for me. Took while to figure the grafana helm values yaml. The comment not showing my indents. :(
`grafana:
  enabled: true
  grafana.ini:
    server:
      domain: a9####3f1.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
      root_url: http://a956####f1.elb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/grafana/
      serve_from_sub_path: true`
this was behind network load balancer in aws.